# Microsoft Word strange behavior with newline of headline

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

starting point:

[image]

I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Headline formatting lost:

[image]

I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again, newline is there:

[image]

What is happening? This annoys me because it happens to me very often.

Comment: Post online a document sample that shows this behavior. Or does this happen on all documents?

Comment: Actually it happens in this document only apparently, I just use it a lot. I tried with a new one and it is ok. I also tried stripping it down for posting it here but the error dissapears. 
I was hoping that someone can explain this behavior.

Comment: Without seeing the document I'm not sure that explanations are possible. Try to save it as RTF and re-open, this sometimes gets rid of strange stuff.

Comment: Seems to have helped thank you. I am not sure if the behavior is still there. I will observe it.

Answer (score 0):

As this problem only arrives with one document that the poster cannot
post for examination, it's hard to give an explanation.

One method I have used often to get rid of strange behavior in Word
is to save it as RTF and re-open, to get rid of the strange stuff.

In the poster's case, this indeed solved this strange behavior.